# specify appsettings while adding database migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

`appsettings` files

1. `appsettings.json`
2. `appsettings.Production.json`
3. `appsettings.Test.json`
4. `appsettings.Debug.json`

all for specific environment but first for common settings.

`appsettings.json` file does not contain connection string, since each environment has its own db.

running `add-migration mig-1` obviously complains that

> Could not find a connection string named 'ConnectionString'.

How can i specify connection string to be taken from `appsettings.Test.json` instead of default one (`appsettings.json`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found answer in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet)

```
add-migration mig-1 -e Test
```

**Note**

EF Core 1.x CLI tools supported an argument called environment which could be use to specify the environment when the commands were run against an ASP.NET Core application. This argument is no longer available in 2.0:

```
-e|--environment <NAME>  The environment to use. Defaults to "Development".
```

With 2.0, you can use the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable instead.

Comment: FYI, in EF Core 2.0.0, you'll need to set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable instead.